# How to Play Video using Gesture Swipe function in VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview, swipe-gesture

I have `VideoView` and I want to play video using gesture swipe function. When user swipes right-to-left playing the next video and when swipe on left-to-right playing the previous video.
It's working fine but when I swipe the last item of an arraylist at that time my application crashes (`array index out of bound`).

Here is my code:

```
class ActivitySwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

        static final String logTag = "ActivitySwipeDetector";
        private Activity activity;
        static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
        private float downX, downY, upX, upY;

        public ActivitySwipeDetector(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public void onRightSwipe() {
            LOGE(logTag, "RightToLeftSwipe!");
            if (mProgressDialog == null) {
                mProgressDialog = ViewUtils.createProgressDialog(mActivity);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            } else {
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }
            i++;
            if (i < mArrayList.size()) {
                LOGD("Index:: :: :: ::", String.valueOf(i));
                Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(mArrayList.get(i));
                videoview.setVideoURI(videoUri);
                videoview.start();
            } else {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        public void onLeftSwipe() {
            LOGE(logTag, "LeftToRightSwipe!");
            if (mProgressDialog == null) {
                mProgressDialog = ViewUtils.createProgressDialog(mActivity);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            } else {
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }
            i--;
            if (i > mArrayList.size()) {
                Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(mArrayList.get(i));
                videoview.setVideoURI(videoUri);
                videoview.start();
            } else {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        public void onDownSwipe() {
            LOGE(logTag, "onTopToBottomSwipe!");
        }

        public void onUpSwipe() {
            LOGE(logTag, "onBottomToTopSwipe!");
            finish();
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    downX = event.getX();
                    downY = event.getY();
                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    upX = event.getX();
                    upY = event.getY();

                    float deltaX = downX - upX;
                    float deltaY = downY - upY;

                    // swipe horizontal?
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)) {
                        if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                            // left or right
                            if (deltaX > 0) {
                                this.onRightSwipe();
                                return true;
                            }
                            if (deltaX < 0) {
                                this.onLeftSwipe();
                                return true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            LOGE(logTag, "Horizontal Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                            return false; // We don't consume the event
                        }
                    }
                    // swipe vertical?
                    else {
                        if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                            // top or down
                            if (deltaY < 0) {
                                this.onDownSwipe();
                                return true;
                            }
                            if (deltaY > 0) {
                                this.onUpSwipe();
                                return true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            LOGE(logTag, "Vertical Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                            return false; // We don't consume the event
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any one have an idea about solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just try below code.

```
class ActivitySwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

static final String logTag = "ActivitySwipeDetector";
private Activity activity;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
private float downX, downY, upX, upY;

public ActivitySwipeDetector(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void onRightSwipe() {
    LOGE(logTag, "RightToLeftSwipe!");
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = ViewUtils.createProgressDialog(mActivity);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    } else {
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    i++;
    if(i>=mArrayList.size())
        i=0;
    if (i < mArrayList.size()) {
        LOGD("Index:: :: :: ::", String.valueOf(i));
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(mArrayList.get(i));
        videoview.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        videoview.start();
    } else {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public void onLeftSwipe() {
    LOGE(logTag, "LeftToRightSwipe!");
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = ViewUtils.createProgressDialog(mActivity);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    } else {
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    i--;
    if(i < 0)
        i= mArrayList.size()-1;

    if (i > mArrayList.size()) {
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(mArrayList.get(i));
        videoview.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        videoview.start();
    } else {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public void onDownSwipe() {
    LOGE(logTag, "onTopToBottomSwipe!");
}

public void onUpSwipe() {
    LOGE(logTag, "onBottomToTopSwipe!");
    finish();
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            // swipe horizontal?
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)) {
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // left or right
                    if (deltaX > 0) {
                        this.onRightSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaX < 0) {
                        this.onLeftSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    LOGE(logTag, "Horizontal Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                    return false; // We don't consume the event
                }
            }
            // swipe vertical?
            else {
                if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // top or down
                    if (deltaY < 0) {
                        this.onDownSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaY > 0) {
                        this.onUpSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    LOGE(logTag, "Vertical Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                    return false; // We don't consume the event
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: still exception is came ?

Comment: check both direction is working or only one direction is not work.

Comment: perfect, now you can check your value is equal to 0 then assign  i =mArrayList.length() before if statement , add one more if

Comment: Can you describe briefly?

Comment: Ok let me check, may be problem in if statement, invert them, can you try

Comment: check now, i update if condition, then also is not work, then you can switch , which is added in left to right add then in right to left.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121065/discussion-between-komal-and-hulk).